# Simple Java Math Applet

Tags: java, applet

How can I create an application that
can display the square root of a number submitted as an argument? So far I have:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class RootApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {
int number; 

public void init() {
number = 225;
}

public void paint(Graphics screen) {
Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen; 
screen2D.drawString("The square root of " + arguments[0] +

" is"
Math.sqrt(number));
}
}
```

But I am obviously missing something according to run time error. `error.

Comment: Missing `+` in the output, first thing...

Comment: where exactly in the output, new to creating applets sorry

Comment: **IF** that was the solution, that's a Compile time error, not Run time.

Answer (score 2):

Your paint method is incorrect. Replace it with below. `drawString` accepts three parameters`String`, `x pos`, `y pos`

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics screen) {
    Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
    screen2D.drawString("The square root of "+number+" - "+(int) Math
            .sqrt(number),10,10);
}
```